# javascript forEach on nodelist

Tags: javascript, foreach

Consider the following code:

```
var els = document.querySelectorAll('.myClassName');

Array.prototype.forEach.call(els, function(el) {
  console.log(el.id);
});
```

The var `els` contains a nodelist, which is not an array, and `forEach` applies on arrays only right?
Is the above code actually a hack?

Comment: From which definition you say nodeList is not an array? it is an array.

Comment: @PawanNogariya: Probably [the specification](https://www.w3.org/TR/domcore/#interface-parentnode): `[NewObject] NodeList querySelectorAll(DOMString selectors);`

Comment: The forEach method expects the variable to be a type array and not the type NodeList (correct me if I am wrong). When I look at the Nodelist in my developer tool from Chrome I can see no forEach available.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> ...and forEach applies on arrays only right?

Nope. `Array.prototype.forEach` is *intentionally generic*, it can be applied to any object that is *array-like*. From [the spec](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/index.html#sec-array.prototype.foreach):

> NOTE2: The `forEach` function is intentionally generic; it does not require that its this value be an Array object. Therefore it can be transferred to other kinds of objects for use as a method.

The spec clearly lays out what properties and/or methods will be used during the processing of `forEach`; as long as the object referenced via `this` during the call has those, `forEach` can be used on that object. That's why using `forEach.call` like that works: The `call` method on function objects (`forEach` is a function object) calls the function using the first argument you give `call` as `this` during the call, and passing along the following arguments as the arguments to the original function. So `Array.prototype.forEach.call(x, y)` calls `forEach` with `this` set to `x` and with the first argument set to `y`. `forEach` doesn't care about the type of `this`, just that it has the relevant properties and methods as described in the specification's algorithm for it.

Most of the `Array.prototype` methods are like that, and indeed many others on the other standard prototypes.

---

Side note: The `NodeList` returned by `querySelectorAll` recently became *iterable* on modern browsers, whcih means: 1.  It works with ES2015+'s `for-of`, and 2. It has `forEach` natively now. (On modern browsers.)

Comment: So when a variable is really an array I can call forEach directly, and if not I use the other approach?

Comment: @poashoas: You can also put a property on it that refers to the `forEach` function, and call the method directly. It's only that arrays inherit the property with the function from `Array.prototype` while other objects don't.

Comment: @poashoas: Mostly, yes. More precisely: So long as you have a reference to an object that has a reference to the `Array.prototype.forEach` function as a property (directly, or because -- like a normal array -- it inherits that from its prototype), you can use `forEach` on it directly. If it doesn't, but it is *array-like*, you can use the `call` approach on it.

Comment: @Bergi I am trying to learn :-D How do you put a property on a NodeList. Something like NodeList.prototype.foreach = function() { for(var i = 0; i < this.length; i++ ){ ... } } ?

Comment: @poashoas: Yes, you could do that, but extending default prototypes can be problematic. If you *do* do it, don't do it with assignment like that because it creates an *enumerable* property. Use `defineProperty`: `Object.defineProperty(NodeList.prototype, "forEach", {value: Array.prototype.forEach});` But again, beware of extending native prototypes that way, and always test on your target JavaScript engines and with the libraries you want to use, in order to: A) Make sure it works (host-provided objects don't have to support it), and B) Check for conflicts.

Comment: @poashoas: I answered before you edited in your implementation. See above, you can *reuse* `Array.prototype.forEach`, you don't have to reimplement it.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder that was really helpfull, I might try some stuff with this