# Are there any particular concerns about using forEach() on NodeLists in pure javascript?

Tags: javascript

I feel like using the basic `for statement` iteration on NodeLists is bulky.
And i plan on implementing `forEach()` on NodeLists.
Am worried that there may be some issues with doing so **i.e** compatibility etc.
From my research, it seems that there is nothing to be worried about. **Check here:** [javascript forEach on nodelist](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37533511/javascript-foreach-on-nodelist?answertab=active#tab-top)
**Question:**
 Is there any concern before implementing it in the production environment ?.

Comment: What do you mean by **concerns**?

Comment: as it's only supported in chrome 51, firefox 50, opera 38 and safari 10 ... then the only possible problem is with IE (and edge?) ... of course you can polyfill, or use `[].forEach.call(nodelist, fn)` in any browser that supports array.forEach

Comment: @JaromandaX Whenever something cool comes out, there will be IE saying **NO, DON'T USE THAT**.

Comment: As IE is a dead browser it's no wonder. That's why I mentioned polyfill and alternate method

Comment: @JaromandaX I have checked compatibility for `array.forEach()` here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach.    And it looks to be performing well except for IE 9. Does this mean it would be unnecessary to add its polyfill to my script ?